# What is :global in sass

Tags: sass

I was going through code of react-datepicker and came across **:global** 
 but could not find any references on it. Any poiters would be helpful [code url](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/src/stylesheets/datepicker-cssmodules.scss)

```
:global {
  @import "datepicker";
}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35417462/5688886) answer can help you.